# What do these AJAX Parameters do with Wikipedia's API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, wikipedia-api

I'm analyzing this CodePen's code, which lets the user search any item within Wikipedia (through Wikipedia's API), and the search engine shows the first 10 results and brief summaries. Analyzing other people's code is (IMO) one of my best ways to learn, along with reading guidebooks and finishing tutorials.

The AJAX code I couldn't understand, is this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
  jsonp: "callback",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: {
    action: "query",
    list: "prefixsearch",
    pssearch: $(".searchbox").val(),
    pslimit: "10",
    format: "json"
  },
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  success: updateSuggest,
  error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Idont understand what these 4 data parameters (`action`, `list`, `pssearch`, `pslimit`) do. What exactly are these 4 parameters' functions... can someone explain them? For example, what does `pssearch` and `list` and `pslimit` do?

I tried looking these terms up on the API, jQuery website and Google searches, but no avail.

Comment: they are "parameters" for the request to wikipedia api - look at the wikipedia api to find out about the wikipedia api - jquery documentation wont help with wikipedia api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These properties are for searching the title prefix:

- `action: "query"`: Queries for data action.
- `list: "prefixsearch"`: "Perform a prefix search for page titles." ([docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Lists), [prefixsearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Prefixsearch))
- `pssearch`: The search string. - ([docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Prefixsearch))
- `pslimit`: Limit the number of entries to returned. - ([docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Prefixsearch))

The [Prefixsearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Prefixsearch) has a short explanation of most of these parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer... could you answer one more question regarding this?  To be specific, I dont understand the diffrence between using [Prefixsearch] and [Search]. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search, It seems Prefixsearch and Search parameters perform identical functions, searching wiki pages that match the search value.

Comment: @Pythonnoob I think Prefixsearch searches titles, and regular Search searches the whole document.

Comment: Prefixsearch searches title prefixes, as the name suggests. It's more or less what you see when you start typing in the search box and it presents you with suggestions. (If you want title search you can use the search API with the `intitle:` keyword in the query.)

Answer (score 2):

They create the url query parameters that will end up looking like:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=prefixsearch.....&format=json
```

when the actual request is made. The api documentation will provide the specifics for each option